# Grouping between different Xpath in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, grouping

I am having concerns in grouping the nodes from different XPath.

My XML is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<rfs>
   <rf id="cc_3_case_33">
        <ref>P028</ref>
        <rcs>
            <rc id="cc_3_rc_199_1022">
                <kws/>
            </rc>
        </rcs>
        <kws>
            <kw>
                <name>AAKAB</name>
                <type>CC</type>
            </kw>
            <kw>
                <name>Bakery</name>
                <type>IS</type>
            </kw>
        </kws>
   </rf>
   <rf id="cc_5_case_85">
        <ref>P086</ref>
        <rcs>
            <rc id="cc_5_rc_199_3772">
                 <kws>
                    <kw>
                        <name>AAKSweAB</name>
                        <type>CC</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>Tefac</name>
                        <type>IS</type>
                    </kw>
                </kws>
            </rc>
        </rcs>
        <kws/>
    </rf>
   <rf id="cc_3_case_8">
          <ref>P013</ref>
         <rcs>
            <rc id="cc_3_rc_199_1179">
             <kws>
                    <kw>
                        <name>AAKAB</name>
                        <type>CC</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>AAK Denmark A/S</name>
                        <type>CC</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>Processes</name>
                        <type>IS</type>
                    </kw>
                </kws>
             </rc>
      </rcs>
        <kws>
            <kw>
                <name>AAKAB</name>
                <type>CC</type>
            </kw>
            <kw>
                <name>Processes</name>
                <type>IS</type>
            </kw>
        </kws>
       </rf>
   <rf id="cc_3_case_89">
          <ref>P085</ref>
        <rcs>
            <rc id="cc_3_rc_199_4057">
                <kws>
                    <kw>
                        <name>AAKAB</name>
                        <type>CC</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>PB</name>
                        <type>IS</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>PBM</name>
                        <type>IS&gt;PB</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>Coasun</name>
                        <type>Product Category</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>Akobisc</name>
                        <type>Product Category&gt;Coasun</type>
                    </kw>
                </kws>
                </rc>
        </rcs>
        <kws>
            <kw>
                <name>AAKAB</name>
                <type>CC</type>
            </kw>
        </kws>
    </rf>
   <rf id="cc_8_case_58">
          <ref>P055</ref>
        <rcs>
            <rc id="cc_8_rc_199_2333">
                <kws>
                    <kw>
                        <name>AAKNetBV</name>
                        <type>CC</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>Special Nutrition</name>
                        <type>IS</type>
                    </kw>
                </kws>
            </rc>
        </rcs>
        <kws>
            <kw>
                <name>AAKSweAB</name>
                <type>CC</type>
            </kw>
            <kw>
                <name>Special Nutrition</name>
                <type>IS</type>
            </kw>
        </kws>
    </rf>
   <rf id="cc_5_case_46">
        <ref>P041</ref>
        <rcs>
            <rc id="cc_5_rc_199_1572">
                <kws>
                    <kw>
                        <name>AAKAB</name>
                        <type>CC</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>AAKSweAB</name>
                        <type>CC</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>PC</name>
                        <type>IS</type>
                    </kw>
                </kws>
            </rc>
            <rc id="cc_5_rc_199_2254">
                  <kws>
                    <kw>
                        <name>AAKSweAB</name>
                        <type>CC</type>
                    </kw>
                    <kw>
                        <name>PC</name>
                        <type>IS</type>
                    </kw>
                </kws>
            </rc>
          </rcs>
        <kws>
            <kw>
                <name>AAKSweAB</name>
                <type>CC</type>
            </kw>
            <kw>
                <name>PC</name>
                <type>IS</type>
            </kw>
        </kws>
    </rf>
   <rf id="cc_0_case_76">
        <ref>P075</ref>
        <rcs>
            <rc id="cc_0_rc_199_3186">
                  <kws/>
            </rc>
        </rcs>
        <kws>
            <kw>
                <name>AAKKamPL</name>
                <type>CC</type>
            </kw>
        </kws>
         </rf>
   <rf id="cc_0_case_72">
         <ref>P071</ref>
         <rcs>
            <rc id="cc_0_rc_199_3170">
               <kws>
                    <kw>
                        <name>CCF</name>
                        <type>IS</type>
                    </kw>
                </kws>
              </rc>
        </rcs>
        <kws>
            <kw>
                <name>AAKKamPL</name>
                <type>CC</type>
            </kw>
        </kws>
    </rf>
 </rfs>
```

The XSLT I wrote is below which is able to group between nodes of similar Xpath..and if the data doesn't exist in same hierarchy, the values are not coming up.

My XSLT :-

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <ccwc id="a">
            <cccs>
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="rfs/rf/rcs/rc/kws=''">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="rfs/rf/kws/kw[type='CC'][1]" group-by="name">
                    <xsl:variable name="ccName1" select="current-group()[1]/name"/>
                    <ccc>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$ccName1"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <name><xsl:value-of select="$ccName1"/></name>
            
                        <cccs>
                            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/../kw[type='IS']" group-by="name">
                                <xsl:variable name="ccName2" select="current-group()[1]/name"/>
                                <ccc>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="concat($ccName1,'_',$ccName2)"/></xsl:attribute>
                                        <name><xsl:value-of select="$ccName2"/></name>
                                    
                                </ccc>
                            </xsl:for-each-group>
                        </cccs>
                    </ccc>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:when>
   <xsl:when test="rfs/rf/rcs/rc/kws!=''">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="rfs/rf/rcs/rc/kws/kw[type='CC'][1]" group-by="name">
                    <xsl:variable name="ccName1" select="current-group()[1]/name"/>
                    <ccc>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="$ccName1"/></xsl:attribute>
                        <name><xsl:value-of select="$ccName1"/></name>
                
                        <cccs>
                            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/../kw[type='IS']" group-by="name">
                                <xsl:variable name="ccName2" select="current-group()[1]/name"/>
                                <ccc>
                                        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="concat($ccName1,'_',$ccName2)"/></xsl:attribute>
                                        <name><xsl:value-of select="$ccName2"/></name>
                                        
                                </ccc>
                            </xsl:for-each-group>
                        </cccs>
                    </ccc>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:when>
 </xsl:choose>
            </cccs>
        </ccwc>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

My Output XML is coming -

```
<ccwc  id="a">
    <cccs>
        <ccc id="AAKAB">
            <name>AAKAB</name>
            <cccs>
                <ccc id="AAKAB_Bakery">
                    <name>Bakery</name>
                </ccc>
                <ccc id="AAKAB_Processes">
                    <name>Processes</name>
                </ccc>
            </cccs>
        </ccc>
        <ccc id="AAKSweAB">
            <name>AAKSweAB</name>
            <cccs>
                <ccc id="AAKSweAB_Special Nutrition">
                    <name>Special Nutrition</name>
                </ccc>
                <ccc id="AAKSweAB_PC">
                    <name>PC</name>
                </ccc>
            </cccs>
        </ccc>
        <ccc id="AAKKamPL">
            <name>AAKKamPL</name>
            <cccs/>
        </ccc>
    </cccs>
</ccwc>
```

Whereas I want the Output XML as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ccwc xmlns:aak="http://www.tridan.it/aak" id="aak">
    <defaultComplexity>NORMAL</defaultComplexity>
    <cccs>
        <ccc id="AAKAB">
            <name>AAKAB</name>
            <cccs>
                <ccc id="AAKAB_Bakery">
                    <name>Bakery</name>
                </ccc>
                <ccc id="AAKAB_Processes">
                    <name>Processes</name>
                </ccc>
            </cccs>
        </ccc>
        <ccc id="AAKSweAB">
            <name>AAKSweAB</name>
            <cccs>
                <ccc id="AAKSweAB_Special Nutrition">
                    <name>Special Nutrition</name>
                </ccc>
                <ccc id="AAKSweAB_PC">
                    <name>PC</name>
                </ccc>
            </cccs>
        </ccc>
        <ccc id="AAKKamPL">
            <name>AAKKamPL</name>
            <cccs>
                <ccc id="AAKKamPL_CCF">
                    <name>CCF</name>
                </ccc>
            </cccs>
        </ccc>
    </cccs>
</ccwc>
```

i.e , concatenating the CC and IS first occurrence values whether both are in rfs/rf/kws/kw or both in rfs/rf/rcs/rc/kws/kw  or one in either of the XPaths.

Any help would be appreciable.Thanks!

Comment: So an `rf` element can have both `kws/kw` and `rcs/rc/kws/kw`. What does your requirement "concatenating the CC and IS first occurrence" refer to, the first in a single `rf` or in the complete document? In generally you might want to explain a bit more which grouping criteria you have, the code that doesn't do the job can't tell us what you want to implement and the verbal description is a bit short to allow (at least me) to understand how the input is mapped to the output, given the input sample is rather long and the values are sometimes hard to relate like `AAKSweAB`.

Comment: Yes, that's correct , for every first occurrence of CC , concatenate the name of first occurrence of IS and place it in a hierarchy creating levels as shown in output XML.
The conditions are :-
1. Both are present in rf/kws/kw.
2. If not found in rf/kws, search for rf/rcs/kws/kw.
3. Also, sometimes the data is like , that CC is found in rf/kws/kw and IS name is present in  rf/rcs/kws/kw.  

With my code I am able to implement point 1. and 2. Need help for point3.